# http media streaming over https by MVMoviePlayerViewController for iphone

Tags: iphone, http, https, streaming, media

I want to implement a function of http media streaming over https by MVMoviePlayerViewController. I try to access https server by NSURLConnection then open media by MVMoviePlayerViewController. I can successfully open the image url by UIWebView through this method under simulator and device and open media url like mp3 and mp4 by MVMoviePlayerViewController under simulator. The strange thing is that I get failed to open media url by MVMoviePlayerViewController under device. The following are error log.

An instance 0x4b4650 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
 (
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x208c20>  Context: 0x0, Property: 0xa8626b0>

The following are some of my code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSString *stringPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxxxx/xxx.mp4";
    NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL URLWithString:[stringPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8St ringEncoding]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlPath];
    NSURLConnection *httpConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
}

- (BOOL)connection : (NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace : (NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection : (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge : (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
{ 
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] > 0) 
    {
        return;
    }

    NSString *authenticationMethod = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod;
    if ([authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTru st])
    {
        SecTrustRef secTrustRef = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:secTrustRef forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"adminr" password:@"admin" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}

- (void)connection : (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse : (NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    assert([httpResponse isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]);

    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse, status code : %d", httpResponse.statusCode);

    NSString *stringPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", testPath];
    NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL URLWithString:[stringPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8St ringEncoding]];

    if ((httpResponse.statusCode / 100) == 2) 
    {
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlPath];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieView Controller];
    } 
}
```

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

1. using NSURLConnection API to connect to an untrusted certification https server.
2. I will receive didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge (NSURLConnection delegate) and get NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust authenticationMethod. I use SecTrustRef and NSURLCredential to access to untrusted certification https server.
3. I will receive didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge (NSURLConnection delegate) and use NSURLCredential to set username and password to access to untrusted certification https server.
4. I all receive didReceiveResponse (NSURLConnection delegate) and get http response statusCode 200 OK.
5. I try to open https media url by MPMoviePlayerViewController API.

Comment: got a similar issue also, I'm using MVMoviePlayerViewController to play a simple m3u8, if that m3u8 will redirect to another m3u8, then ONLY the device cannot play the video, with the `AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers...` error prompts. Works fine with normal m3u8, didn't make a difference if I switch between ARC or non ARC